# create-react-app with spring boot, setting proxy server

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, http-proxy

I have a `create-react-app` hosted on `react.example.in` and springboot app "demo.example.in". I am making login request as

> url:"react.example.in/auth"

which is expected to return an object containing token as a response but returning html as a response with `200 OK` status code. Can anyone guide me how to properly setup proxy?

In my react app `package.json` is as follows:

> "proxy":"https://demo.example.in"

```
axios({
method:'POST',
url:'/auth',
data:{username:'example@gmail.com',password:'123456789'}
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
}).catch(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

i am getting index.html which contains root element as a response.

Comment: you may have to call `demo.example.in/auth` in url ?

Comment: please check out my login request i edited it